# When Jamaah of Masjid is audible from my home and I pray in my home, does that make my Salah a Jamaah Salaah?

Tags: salat, jamaat

My home is nearer to Masjid (mosque). All conducted Jamat in Masjid are clearly audible from my home. I have the following questions (please answer in both gender's view):

1. Shall I do Salah by using Jamaah from my home. That is, shall I follow the Imam for my Salah? Is it permissible in Sunnah?
2. If answer for my first question is yes, will my Salah be considered as Jamaah Salah? That is, shall I get the reward of Jamaah Salah?

Comment: as Shia It's not Jamaah at all. From Sunnah I didn't know :( ...

Answer (score 3):

```
                                   In the name of Allah
```

To the best of my knowledge, there is a limited (specified) space between the individuals of Salah-al-Jama'ah (المصلین), it doesn't seem to be accepted in that location as you remarked:

> When Jamaah of Masjid is audible from my home, does my Salaah consider
>   as Jamaah Salaah, if I do it from my home?

Otherwise everyone could say his prayer as Jama'ah since it can be audible from the television as well. But as much as I searched, it doesn't seem to be a related hadith that you can say your salah in your home as Jama'ah ...

---

I am not aware of your sect, but as (at least) a general related information, according to Imam Khomeini (briefly):

> Your salah-al-Jama'ah won't be invalidated if your distance with the
>   Imam al-Jama'ah and Ma'moon (the person who says the prayers behind
>   the Imam-al-Jama'ah) is less than a long step (foot) [about one
>   meter], but it would be invalidated if it is more than this.
>
> ر.ک: امام خمینى، سید روح اللّٰه، توضیح المسائل (محشّٰى)، ج‌1، ص 784، م
>   1437، دفتر انتشارات اسلامى، قم، هشتم، 1424 ه‍ ق.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa23156)

Answer (score 0):

No, your salah won't be considered Jamah salah. In fact, if you follow the imam and don't recite the surahs then it would be invalid. If your mosque is near then you should go to pray there except if you are disabled.